# How to find the equation of a 3D straight line when given two points?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not even sure if my method fo 2D lines is correct, but here is how I proceed for 2D lines:

Since this is a straight line, the equation for the line can be expressed as $ax+y=b$ (please correct me if this step  is wrong), where I have to find a and b. Let's assume I am given two points of the line $(1,2)$ and $(3,8)$. I proceed to solve the system of two equations with 2 unknown variables, a and b:

$1\cdot a+2=b$

$3\cdot a + 8=b$

After solving, I find that $a=-3$ and $b=-1$. Ultimately, I was able to find the equation for the straight line that intersects these 2 points, namely $y=3x-1$.

If I try the above method for a 3D straight line instead, so $ax+by+z=c$ (correct me if wrong), the method instantly fails because I have only 2 points for 3 unkown variables, so I can't just solve the system of equatons and get th vaules for a, b and c.

At the moment, I am trying to find the straight line that goes through $(1,3,2)$ and $(2,1,0)$.

Comment: The issue with your 2D line equation is that you are calling the slope $ \ -a \ $  and the $ \ y-$intercept is $ \ b \ \ , $  so you have enough information for the variables involved.  In three dimensions, there is not one slope, but _three_, so you have to set up more than one equation, for which **Aiden Chow**  shows a couple of methods.

Comment: The problem is here: _"If I try the above method for a 3D straight line instead, so $ax+by+z=c$ "_. In 3D $ax+by+z=c$ gives a plane; you restricted only one variable so you can still move about in two free dimensions. You need two equations to specify a line, as in Aiden Chow's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the parametric form of a line.

The vector from $(1,3,2)$ to $(2,1,0)$ is $\langle2-1,1-3,0-2\rangle=\langle1,-2,-2\rangle$.

So, the parametric form of the line going through $(1,3,2)$ and $(2,1,0)$ would be:
$$\begin{align}x&=1+t\\y&=3-2t\\z&=2-2t\end{align}$$
If you wish, you can also solve for $t$ in each parametric equation and convert it to symmetric form:
$$x-1=\frac{3-y}2=\frac{2-z}2$$

Answer (score 3):

For two points $a$ and $b$
in any number of dimensions,
the line from $a$ to $b$ is
$L(t)=a+t(b-a)$
for $0 \le t \le 1$.

This is $a$ for
$t=0$,
$b$ for $t=1$,
and goes linearly.

You can look at
the individual coordinates
if you want.